# Visual Studio 2008 and Oracle 10g

Tags: .net, database, visual-studio-2008, oracle

At work we have just started developing in C#.NET using VS2008 and we need to connect to Oracle databases.

The problem is that we are still using Oracle 10g servers and Oracle provide four install options:

- Install the Oracle 10g DAC with tools for VS2005 / VS2003
- Install the Oracle 11g DAC with tools for VS2008
- Install Oracle 10g DAC
- Install Oracle 11g DAC

http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/windows/odpnet/index.html

We would prefer to use the 10g DAC but with VS2008 tools...

I'm wondering if anyone knows of any issues we might face using the 11g DAC on a 10g database - are the DACs backwards compatible?

So far it seems ok and we can connect and make queries with it but I have little experience working with Oracle databases, thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using Visual Studio 2008 with Oracle 11g DAC (with tools) running against Oracle 10gR2 for many months now without any real issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Oracle 10.g is working with Visual Studio 2008 (3.5 framework) Application, But when i added unit testing it gets failed
I tried ORA connection string method also but the error exist